# Creating Data Lake Storage with terraform says datalakestore.Client#GetProperties even though It has full permissions

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating Azure Data lake storage with `Terraform`. I am authenticating via Service Principle and it has all roles assigned "`Storaage, Owner, Storage Contributor, Storage Blob data owner, Storage blob data contributor`" etc.. But it still fails with below error

**The code I use:**

```
 resource "azurerm_storage_account" "syn_st" {
   name                     = "st${var.prefix}${var.postfix}"
   resource_group_name      = var.rg_name
   location                 = var.location
   account_tier             = var.storage_account_tier
   account_replication_type = var.storage_account_replication_type
   account_kind             = var.storage_account_kind
   is_hns_enabled           = var.hns_enabled
 }
    
 resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "st_role_admin_c" {
   scope                = azurerm_storage_account.syn_st.id
   role_definition_name = "Contributor"
   principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
 }
    
 resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "st_role_admin_sbdc" {
   scope                = azurerm_storage_account.syn_st.id
   role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
   principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
 }
    
 resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "st_adls" {
   name               = "default"
   storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.syn_st.id
    
   depends_on = [
     azurerm_role_assignment.st_role_admin_sbdc
   ]
 }
```

Error:

```
 datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: "" error: EOF │
```

**My Service Principal which I use have full access like below:**

[image]

Not sure what's going wrong here. Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are explicitly the assigning the role Storage Blob Data Contributor to Service Principal or user  using azurerm_role_assignment and performing the data lake creation at a time, there may be chances of it being failed as, role assignment may take some time to propagate and in the mean time adls gen2 may nt have required permissions.

- So please make sure apply roles first , give some time to be
  reflected in portal  and then try to create the  resource
  azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2
- And try to upgrade terraform version.

I have `contributer` and azure `storage data contributer` roles already assigned
I could create the resources successfully.
Also ***make sure you have owner role*** for yourself.

[image]

***Portal o/p:***

[image]

[image]

Also try adding Subnet in storage account network rules code .It may sometimes due to the firewall being blocked or it being created in that same region.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa" {
resource_group_name = 
storage_account_name = 
default_action = "Deny"
bypass = ["AzureServices"]
virtual_network_subnet_ids = [module.virtual_network.subnet["public"].id]
}
```

**References:**

1. [azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem:
   Failure responding to request:
   StatusCode=403 · Issue
   · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6659)
2. [suddenly unable to deploy a container file system.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/726510/suddenly-unable-to-deploy-a-container-file-system.html)

Comment: Thanks @kavyasaraboju-MT for reply, actually we are doing this as part of automation... do you mean that applying roles should not be part of automation ? If yes, my question is " in our case we are assigning contributor role during the terraform work flow on just created storage account " You mean to write up a sleep tiem before creating file system ? Other question is "if I service principal storage contributor will it apply to all future storage account that gonna create ? or we should give after creation storage account . Meanwhile I will try your suggestions